# How to replace spaces with %20 while sharing dynamic data through URLs to Whatsapp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode

In this code, I have dynamic colleges in my URL through get I am fetching data through URL and I'm using CodeIgniter.

Now, I want to share content with friends through Whatsapp.

When I click on Whatsapp link, it redirects me on Whatsapp Web, and after scanning QR code and then send to any friend it shows spaces in my `$colleges` like a b c but I want `a%20b%20c`.

So, how can I do this ? Please help me.

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo base_url(); ?>college/<?php $strings = $college; $collegesss = preg_replace('/\s+/','%20', $string); echo $collegesss; ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
    <div style="color: #fff;">
        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Whatsapp
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php is what you're chasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) from PHP library.

Something like that:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo base_url(); ?>college/<?php echo urlencode($college); ?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
    <div style="color: #fff;">
        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Whatsapp
    </div>
</a>
```